# Animation Lags on iOS devices for apps designed in Adobe Flash Pro

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, rendering, flash-cs6

I am developing iOS app and android app using adobe AIR and Flash CS6.The app contains lots of animations. Since Bitmap images do not give a good quality, **I have kept the images in Vector form** only. It runs fine on android devices but when I publish it on iOS device many animation lags. How can I solve this without affecting the quality of my animations? I am using **AIR SDK version 4.0 and GPU rendering method**. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a few things you could try:

- use TweenMax/TweenLite for your animations as the GreenSock library is optimized for performance
- try setting **cacheAsBitmap** to true on the vector you're animating
- convert vectors to cached bitmap data (http://esdot.ca/site/2012/fast-rendering-in-air-cached-spritesheets)
- try see if using "direct" mode for rendering yields better performance; from what I've experienced GPU is not well suited for vectors

Comment: To add to this already good answer, Adobe actively recommends against using GPU mode when using lots of vector graphics or animating them. GPU mode is optimized for bitmap rendering. Additionally, make sure you are testing animations on either a standard debug build or an Ad Hoc release build. You will notice lag in a fast debug and even standard debug (compared to Ad hoc). You can also try increasing the framerate from the default 24fps, which is generally low for smooth animation